# Sonargraph Integration- Unable to load custom metrics file SonargraphMetrics.properties

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonata-admin, sonarqube-scan

When running the jenkins jobs with build option "Execute SonarQube Scanner" getting below error:

```
INFO: Sonargraph Integration: Loaded standard metrics file '/com/hello2morrow/sonargraph/integration/sonarqube/SonargraphMetrics.properties'
ERROR: Sonargraph Integration: Unable to load custom metrics file '/root/.sonargraphintegration/SonargraphMetrics.properties'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/.sonargraphintegration/SonargraphMetrics.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.hello2morrow.sonargraph.integration.sonarqube.SonargraphMetricsProvider.loadCustomMetrics(SonargraphMetricsProvider.java:275)
    at
```

Sonar version: Community EditionVersion 7.9.1

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue using v5.0.0 of the plugin and fixed it by using v5.1.

https://github.com/sonargraph/sonar-sonargraph-integration/releases